# Magento 2 : How to Detect Checkout Step Change

Tags: magento2, javascript, uicomponent, knockoutjs, requirejs

I am trying to figure out the best method of detecting a step change in Magento 2's checkout. For example going from shipping details to payment, or vice versa.

I have done some digging and in `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/step-navigator.js` I can use `next()` which fires on the continue button, and `navigateTo()` which fires when a user clicks on the checkoutstep directly - but both methods seem rather hacky, there must be a cleaner way to detect a step change **regardless of how and which step**.

I was hoping for a `stepChange()` function or something similar that fires whenever a checkout step change happens.

My question:

**What is the best method to trigger my custom JS when a checkout step change occurs?**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can register a handle for when the hash code changes, i.e. `$(window).hashchange(callBack)`.

This is what happens in `Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/progress-bar.js`:

```
$(window).hashchange(_.bind(stepNavigator.handleHash, stepNavigator));
```

This causes the `stepNavigator.handleHash` function to execute whenever the step changes because changing steps using `next` or `navigateTo` changes the window's hash.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, apologies I didn't give the full bounty I wasn't aware there was a deadline for it.

Comment: A great answer/suggestion.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Good question. I do not know what is the best way (I'm interested to other answers) but i think that adding a custom event to the `.next()` or `.isProcessed()` function and pass to it the current step could be a pretty good solution.

Comment: I don't think adding it to next is a good idea as then it wouldn't fire when you go back a step